# JRE system library missing tools.jar

Tags: eclipse, classpath, java

I am using Ubuntu 12.04(LTS). In my project in Eclipse I need to use the com.sun.tools.attach package. However, my JRE system library does not include the tools.jar file which contains the package.

I tried installing different JREs and JDKs for both Java 6 and 7. What I noticed is that some of them have the mentioned jar file in their libs folder but Eclipse still fails to include it in my classpath upon selection of the JRE. Referencing tools.jar directly solves the problem but since this is a shared project I am not allowed to modify the classpath and thus this is not a viable solution for me.

My friend is using a MAC with the same version of Eclipse and the default JRE and does not have this problem. What we found out is that for him tools.jar is part of classes.jar which is not the case in my setup (I don't have classes.jar whatsoever).

What do you think might be the source of this problem?

Comment: Tools.jar is part of the JDK not the JRE.

Answer (score 4):

**The issue is that the JDK contains the tools.jar file (neither of the JREs do).**

It is easy to solve the problem, you have to specify the default runtime environment to use either for the project or for the whole workspace. Change that to any of the installed JDKs.

The easiest way is probably going to *Window --> Preferences --> Java --> Installed JREs*, and selecting the JDK instead of the JRE. All the projects use this setting by default.

Comment: It is true that thee is a tools.jar inside the libs folder of the JDK folder. Unfortunately, when I changed it in eclipse it did not resolve the issue. Am I doing something wrong? I used java-6-openjdk.

Comment: Just to clarify things, when do you encounter the issue? Is it an Ant script that fails? Does it help if you specify the JDK for eclipse to use instead of the JRE in the `eclipse.ini` file with the `-vm` switch? Also, [take a look here](http://www.gamefromscratch.com/post/2011/11/15/Telling-Eclipse-to-use-the-JDK-instead-of-JRE.aspx).

Comment: It is not an Ant script. I tried following the tutorial you mentioned but that didn't solve the problem. However, I tried compiling the class from the terminal using the javac command. It couldn't recognize the package until I explicitly specified the classpath (-cp) argument in javac to point to /usr/lib/jvm/java-6-openjdk/lib/*. That solved the problem. To me it looks like the tools.jar doesn't get picked up for some reason by Eclipse even when I set the Installed JREs setting to java-6-openjdk. Maybe that is going to shed more light onto it..

Comment: Also I just realized that when I do java -version in the terminal I get "1.7.0_09" and when I do javac -version I get "1.6.0_24". That causes a problem later when I try to run the code I get the an exception in main being like: "Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: NameOfClass (wrong name: path_to_class/NameOfClass)"

Comment: Now that sheds the light on the issue: Eclipse was started by a JRE, not a JDK, that was causing you trouble (as you pointed out, the compiler wasn't in your classpath, neither the required `tools.jar` file).

Comment: Also, teh exception you get is because you're either not standing in the bin directory (remember, you must run java from the package root of the classfiles which are put under `bin` by Eclipse by default).

Answer (score 0):

I had exactly the same problem on Ubuntu 12.10 and in my case managed to solve it by adding a reference to the current Java binaries folder to my `PATH` variable.

```
PATH="$PATH:/usr/local/java/current/bin"
```

Or

```
PATH="$PATH:$JAVA_HOME/bin"
```

Just edit either `.profile` or `.bash_profile` in your `/home/<user>` folder and you should be fine. If these files doesn't exist just create one of them.

Note: make sure your are using JDK and not JRE